# change cell color based on number of days between two dates with google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

With Google Sheets I need to change the cell color according to the difference between the two dates. I need to do this according to today's date. I get today's date with the =TODAY() code. I write the date of 20 days ago in the cell. If the difference is more than 20 days, I want to make it red.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't have an output sample. I want something based on a single cell. Here is the function I use and it doesn't work;
=DATEDIF(Today()-a1)>5 
I want to subtract the date in cell a1 from today's date and change the cell color if it is greater than 5.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

in conditional formatting choose a custom formula and use:

```
=(TODAY()-A1)>20
```